# 0xC0000005 Error happens in print function

Tags: mfc

Here's the code below.

```
void SignalView::OnFilePrintPreview()
{
 if(RcursorPosX-LcursorPosX<=0){
  AfxMessageBox(_T("Please set cursor positions.\nYou can only print out the area between left and right cursors"));
  return;
 }
 CScrollView::OnFilePrintPreview();
}

BOOL SignalView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
 if(RcursorPosX-LcursorPosX>100*4*2)
 RcursorPosX = LcursorPosX+100*4*2; //800 = 100 cursor x 4(gridX) x 2(zoomX)

 pInfo->SetMinPage(1);
 pInfo->SetMaxPage(1);

 return DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);      //<===========
}

void SignalView::OnBeginPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
 PRINTDLG* pPrintDlg = new PRINTDLG;
 AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(pPrintDlg);
 DEVMODE* lpDevMode = (DEVMODE*)::GlobalLock(pPrintDlg->hDevMode);        

 lpDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE; 

 while(!pDC->ResetDC(lpDevMode));
 ::GlobalUnlock(pPrintDlg->hDevMode);    
 delete pPrintDlg;
}
```

I'm trying to use print functions. But I remade it because I deleted it and made a new class again which is derived from `CScrollView`, so I don't use the original view that was made from the beginning.

And now, I achieved what I want but the problem is that an error happens when I try to call and close print event `OnFilePrintPreview()` around 30-40 times, then it would shut down with an error message `0xC0000005`.

And it happens from the function `DoPreparePrinting(pInfo)`, and then it goes to `COMMDLG_AFXCTXFUNC(BOOL ,PrintDlgW,(LPPRINTDLGW unnamed1),(unnamed1))` in `afxcomctl32.inl` file and then it provokes an error message.

Why does this problem happen? And does the code seem to go the right direction?

P.S.
The error happens this part in disassembly mode.

```
COMMDLG_AFXCTXFUNC(BOOL ,PrintDlgW,(LPPRINTDLGW unnamed1),(unnamed1))
7824CD80  mov         edi,edi  
7824CD82  push        ebp  
7824CD83  mov         ebp,esp  
7824CD85  mov         eax,dword ptr [unnamed1]  
7824CD88  push        eax  
7824CD89  call        AfxGetModuleState (780F3320h)  
7824CD8E  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+94h]  
7824CD94  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ecx+4]  
7824CD97  call        CCommDlgWrapper::_PrintDlgW (7824CDB0h)  
7824CD9C  pop         ebp         //<======= it's stopped at this point.
7824CD9D  ret         4
```

Comment: Use the debugger to find out where the crash happens by looking on call stack.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I commented on the code above. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(!pDC->ResetDC(lpDevMode));
    ::GlobalUnlock(pPrintDlg->hDevMode);
```

This looks like trouble. If loop condition is true the first time and the second time, then there is no guarantee that it will eventually stop.

The following may not be the cause of your error, but you should try to follow these procedures in general.

When declaring new variables set them to zero, so all structure members are zero:

```
PRINTDLG* pPrintDlg = new PRINTDLG;
memset(pPrintDlg, 0, sizeof(pPrintDlg));
```

Some structures require to know the size. This has to do with Microsoft version control:

```
pPrintDlg->lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLG);
```

In this case you don't need to use `new` to allocate `pPrintDlg` (but it won't cause problems if you do)

You should be able to intercept the request for printing (before printer device context is created) and change to landscape mode, so Print dialog box is shown in landscape mode.

```
void SignalView::OnFilePrint()
{
    PRINTDLG printDlg = { 0 };
    printDlg.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLG);
    if (AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(&printDlg))
    {
        if (printDlg.hDevMode)
        {
            DEVMODE *dm = (DEVMODE*)::GlobalLock(printDlg.hDevMode);
            if (dm)
            {
                dm->dmFields |= DM_ORIENTATION;
                dm->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
                ::GlobalUnlock(printDlg.hDevMode);
            }
        }
    }

    CScrollView::OnFilePrint();
}
```

Message map should look like this:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(SignalView, CScrollView)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, OnFilePrint)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_DIRECT, OnFilePrint)
    //**************************************************
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_PREVIEW, OnFilePrintPreview)
    //**************************************************
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

User can change the print mode back to portrait in print dialog box. You can repeat the same code in `OnBeginPrinting` if you want to force landscape.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have to make print preview. I already made with print dialog but I deleted it, because I couldn't find a way to show up print preview mode if I will keep using print dialog. Moreover, the preview should show a landscape view to the users, so that's why I used the landscape mode before settings. Is there a way of using print preview with print dialog?? If not, how can I make it with normal print view functions.

Comment: See the edit, if it helps. It should force landscape. You should also be able to do this in `void CMyView::OnFilePrintPreview()`

Comment: Thank you for your edit. But, it didn't show up any preview.. If I want to make the preview show up before the dialog box, how should I fix it from your code?

Comment: I don't understand. The question is *"Error in print function"*. You should edit your question and show more code, including SignalView's message map, and explain the error in more detail.

Comment: Thank you. It did help. But there still exists one problem. When it calls AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(&printdlg.m_pd); in your edit code, it happens an error message with COMMDLG_AFXCTXFUNC(BOOL ,PrintDlgW,(LPPRINTDLGW unnamed1),(unnamed1)) function in afxcomctl32.inl file. Could you give me some solutions?

Comment: I can't duplicate that error. `"afxcomctl32.inl"` seems to be for specific version of Visual Studio. I edited my code once more. See if you can run the `PRINTDLG` code in `CMainFrame::OnCreate` after `CMDIFrameWnd::OnCreate` (that's not good practice, I mean just for testing). Comment out other references to `PRINTDLG` (the once you wrote yourself).

Comment: I didn't use MDI, I used SDI. How should I test in this case ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105510/discussion-between-barmak-shemirani-and-sean).

Comment: Do you have `OnFilePrintPreview` in message map? like above code

Comment: I changed to Release Mode now, and it works really well without any error message. To check that the problem came from the code or Debug mode, I put the code that I used before in Debug mode, in Release Mode, and tested. It really worked well! I really don't know why the problem only happened in Debug mode, but your answers are so much helpful to me.